# filedescriptor out of range in select() - a file descriptor leakage?

Tags: python, sockets, file-descriptor

I have wrote a wrapper for python's `socket` module in which I use `select.select` with an `rlist` containing only the socket object with a `timeout`, in order to allow `recv` with a timeout. It looks (more or less) like this:

```
def recv(self, timeout):
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.socket], [], [], timeout)
    if ready:
        return self.socket.recv(4096)
    return ""
```

So what it does, mainly, is waiting for the socket to be ready for `timeout` seconds; if not ready by then, it returns an empty string, and if it is ready, it recieves what's in it, up to the common limitation of some power of 2 bytes.

This works great, normally; however, lately I started encountering exceptions in the select line in the code, which looks like that:

```
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

The program I wrote, which uses that wrapper I've written, is a script which runs a few hours. It looks like each time I run it, though, it fails with this `ValueError` after ~40 minutes. It looks like there's some leakage of my file descriptors. However, these are only sockets, and I believe I am closing them properly, as the `.close()` method of my wrapper looks like that:

```
def close(self):
    self.socket.close()
```

I am using python 2.7. I do not understand my problem well enough to produce a self-contained running example which demonstrates my problem.

## Edit

The initialization of the wrapped socket object looks like that:

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
self.socket.setblocking(0)
```

Comment: From documentation of 'select' module(http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/select.html#module-select): "You may also define a wrapper class yourself, as long as it has an appropriate fileno() method (that really returns a file descriptor, not just a random integer)". As mentioned in the docs. does your wrapper class has the 'fileno' method ?

Comment: I am not selecting my wrapper class; I am selecting what it wraps, which is a real python socket object (`self.socket`).